# How to transition screen between SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't transition screen in swift UI. Like from login page to home page?

I used PresentationLink and NavigationLink but it seems like they have a pop up screen.

PresentationLink(destination: someView, detail: )

Comment: What kind of transition did you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

you can use navigation button for navigation you can add images and texts to it same as Views, add more details to your question with your UI image for more clarity.

```
 NavigationButton(destination: YourCustomView()) { 

}
```

Comment: how to hide navigation back button in swiftUI?

Comment: @DanielKua for hiding back button use `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`.